# fetch data from datastore more than 2000

Tags: google-app-engine

I tried to fetch data from a datastore. But I can fetch the limited data. What is the maximum data can be fetched from a datastore using "Query"? Also can I add 2000+ data in a datastore using a loop or any other way?. How to code to fetch 2000+ data from a datastore.

Comment: There's no limit; however in development, the stub datastore API has issues with returning more than 2000.

Comment: I want add 2000+ data in a database how to add it.